# wp_enqueue_script inside shortcode

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

hi so I used a great tutorial off of http://scribu.net/wordpress/optimal-script-loading.html and I am having trouble loading the scripts when a shortcode called lightbox is used here is my code. I am at the page when it is called wanted to check with someone to see if it is properly written.

```
add_shortcode('lightbox', 'lightbox_handler');
function lightbox_handler($atts) {
 $base = get_stylesheet_directory_uri();
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-mousewheel', $base . '/js/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-fancybox', $base . '/js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-fancybox-buttons', $base . '/js/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js', array('jquery-fancybox'), '1.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-fancybox-media', $base . '/js/jquery.fancybox-media.js', array('jquery-fancybox'), '1.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-fancybox-thumbs', $base . '/js/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js', array('jquery-fancybox'), '1.0', true);

    wp_enqueue_style('jquery-fancybox', $base . '/css/jquery.fancybox.css', false, '1.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_style('jquery-fancybox-buttons', $base . '/css/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css', array('jquery-fancybox'), '1.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_style('jquery-fancybox-thumbs', $base . '/css/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css', array('jquery-fancybox'), '1.0', true);
}
function lightbox( $atts, $content = null )  {

$defaults = apply_filters( 'toggle_shortcode_args',
    array(
    'title' => '',
    'id' => '',
    'type' => '',
    'rel' => '',
    'url' => '',
    )
);


extract( shortcode_atts( $defaults, $atts ) );

        $html .= '<a class="'.$id.'" rel="'.$rel.'" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="'.$url.'" title="'.$title.'"><img src="'.$url.'" alt="" />';
        $html .= '</a>';

    return $html;
}
```

Comment: Multi-post: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/74681/wp-register-script-and-wp-register-style-when-shortcode-is-used

Answer (score 5):

First point: that tutorial is based on an old version of WordPress; don't follow that one. Now:

The handle you specify in [wp_register_script()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script) must be unique. You are reusing the same handle (fancybox) for all scripts; this won't work. Give each one a different handle, e.g. 'jquery-mousewheel', 'jquery-fancybox', 'jquery-fancybox-buttons', etc. Try to stick to established naming habits that WordPress uses, see [wp_enqueue_script() default scripts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Default_scripts_included_with_WordPress) for examples.

If you want your scripts to be output in the footer, just say so in wp_register_script() (which you have); there is no need to use the wp_footer action. Styles should be output in the header anyway, not the footer.

You can tell WordPress to register and enqueue scripts and stylesheets for output with one call each: [wp_enqueue_script()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) and [wp_enqueue_style()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style). There is no need to register, then enqueue, in your simple case.

The best action hook for registering and enqueueing scripts is '[wp_enqueue_scripts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts)'. Try to only use that one except in special circumstances.

Bonus points: where a script name already includes the version number, you can suppress the extra '?ver=nnn' that WordPress tacks on by passing null as the version string.

And finally, [get_stylesheet_directory_uri()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri) doesn't take any arguments.

NB: this gets your script working. One thing your linked tutorial does differently is only output your scripts conditionally, but there are better tutorials on that subject linked at the bottom of the wp_enqueue_scripts() manual page. First, get your site working!

```
class fancy{
    static function init() {
        add_shortcode('lightbox', array(__CLASS__, 'handle_shortcode'));

        add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array(__CLASS__, 'wp_enqueue_scripts'));
    }

    static function handle_shortcode($atts) {
        self::$add_script = true;

        // actual shortcode handling here
    }

    static function wp_enqueue_scripts() {
        $base = get_stylesheet_directory_uri();
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-mousewheel', $base . '/js/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-fancybox', $base . '/js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-fancybox-buttons', $base . '/js/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js', array('jquery-fancybox'), '1.0', true);
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-fancybox-media', $base . '/js/jquery.fancybox-media.js', array('jquery-fancybox'), '1.0', true);
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-fancybox-thumbs', $base . '/js/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js', array('jquery-fancybox'), '1.0', true);

        wp_enqueue_style('jquery-fancybox', $base . '/css/jquery.fancybox.css', false, '1.0', true);
        wp_enqueue_style('jquery-fancybox-buttons', $base . '/css/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css', array('jquery-fancybox'), '1.0', true);
        wp_enqueue_style('jquery-fancybox-thumbs', $base . '/css/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css', array('jquery-fancybox'), '1.0', true);
    }
}

fancy::init();
```

PS: I suspect that jquery.fancybox.pack.js is a packed (i.e. minified) version of jquery.fancybox.js, so use that one as 'jquery-fancybox' if it is; you don't need both.

Comment: thanks for the help, but i tried your code and it still doesn't register , i have also removed the add_action for the shortcode to see if it works by itself and still no luck.

Comment: Where are you putting this code? e.g. functions.php in your theme folder?

Comment: PS: you can use a class, or not, the class is just being used in this code as a convenient way to wrap your functions in a namespace really, i.e. to prevent name clashes with plugins etc.

Comment: So how will it be called? Is your shortcodes.php being required() or included() by your functions.php?

Comment: Yes, but... where? Is this in functions.php, or shortcodes.php? How will WordPress know to load your code? And why have you put your enqueue_* calls in the function for processing the shortcode now?

Comment: functions.php i require_once which calls all my shortcodes that works and I am using hobo's post that uses a condition to call it once I use it below http://scribu.net/wordpress/conditional-script-loading-revisited.html

Comment: Reading what you wrote above, I interpret that your shortcode.php file includes_once your functions.php file; is that right? If so, no. In functions.php, require() your shortcodes.php file.

Comment: JFTR: have you read the linked WordPress manual pages yet?

Comment: you have it backwards in functions.php i require_once shortcodes.php

Comment: Is there any indication that your shortcode script is being called? e.g. when you visit a page with the shortcode in it, can you see any evidence that the shortcode is replaced with something?

Comment: Can you paste it all into a pastebin or something, so we can see exactly what is in the file please? And can you provide a link to this?

Comment: I just looked at your link, the scripts are there; view source and see bottom of page.

Comment: Sorry, not an answer to your original question, and I'm out of time. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to `wp_register_script` needs to be unique for each script (see [the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script)), so you might need names like "fancybox.mousewheel", "fancybox", "fancybox.buttons" etc to differentiate.  I'd check, but I suspect you only need one of fancybox.js and fancybox.pack.js - I'd think the pack file is a minified version of fancybox.js

But what version of WordPress are you using?  The link at the top of the tutorial you mentioned shows a cleaner way to do it in WordPress 3.3+, removing the need for the class.

Comment: I am using the latest version 3.4.2 so I can remove the need for a class? and thx for a quick response hobo so should i add multiple ids and multiple wp_print_scripts();

Comment: I've never used `wp_print_scripts` (I've used `wp_enqueue_script`), but I'd be pretty sure you'd have to call it multiple times, yes (you do with `wp_enqueue_script`).  Though I guess you might be able to set the dependencies so you only have to call the last one, and it includes everything it depends on.

Comment: I see you've edited the question.  Your call to `wp_print_scripts` is wrong - pass it an array instead: wp_print_scripts(array('fancy-wheel','fancybox','fancy-buttons','fancy-thumbs','fancy-css','fancy-buttons','fancy-thumbs'));

Comment: Sorry, missed the bit about you using 3.4.2.  Yep, you can remove the need from the class.  See the link right at the top of the tutorial (to http://scribu.net/wordpress/conditional-script-loading-revisited.html)

Comment: okay so it would be add_shortcode('lightbox', 'my_shortcode_handler');
 
function my_shortcode_handler($atts) {
 wp_enqueue_script('jquery-mousewheel', $base . '/js/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
 
 // actual shortcode handling here
}